# There was an error with the request: Cleartext HTTP traffic to localhost not permitted

Tags: http, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am working on ionic 4 using capacitor. I tried to call an api from localhost but am getting this error

`There was an error with the request: Cleartext HTTP traffic to localhost not permitted`!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since android 9 they try to push people to use https APIs instead of http.
But there are ways to disable it.

The simple answer is to allow http in your whole app by modifying the `AndroidManifest.xml` and adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `application`

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

For a more fine tuned domain dependent approach I recommend reading this:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted

Comment: Hello tobika, 

Thanks for your reply. I've modified AndroidManifest.xml and i got another error message : 

`There was an error with the request: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:80` Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you should start another question? just to be sure (because maybe I missunderstood), you are also calling the api that is running on localhost? localhost in the android app is the telephone and not your computer, just in case the problem is there